# Biblatex command that prints a bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex

Is there a `biblatex` command that prints a bibliography entry? A command that prints this entry for example: *Prunescu and Sin 2013 - Bioresource Technology Vol. 150C, p. 393-403* which is defined in my `.bib` file.

I need it on a slide in `beamer`.

Comment: Yes, use `\fullcite{<entry>}`. This assumes you've processed your `.bib` correctly (either via BibTeX or biber).

Comment: Is there a way to make it print the short version of author names? (full name is stored in the .bib file). \fullcite prints: Prunescu Remus and Gürkan Sin. I would like R. Prunescu and G. Sin.

Comment: @remus If *that* is your question, you might want to edit it to clarify what you *actually* want, your question can then be re-opened. Alternatively, ask a new question.

Comment: I found my answer: `firstinits=true`. I won't reopen the question. It's in the documentation.